# Better idiom for filling a C++ array from a NumericVector

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am using `Rcpp` to wrap an algorithm written (not by me) in C-like C++ (no STL, no boost, no nothing, as far as I can tell).  You can see the implemented algorithm [here](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/kmeans/kmeans.cpp) (I'm wrapping `kmeans_w_03`).  Consequently I'm passing in a `numeric` vector from R, which then needs to be converted to a `double` array.

Currently I'm looping element-by-element and filling the one from the 'tother, like this:

```
SEXP testfn(SEXP weightvec, SEXP cluster_num_k){
    Rcpp::NumericVector weightR(weightvec) ;
    int point_num = weightR.size();
    double weight[point_num] ;
    for(int i = 0; i < point_num; ++i) {
      weight[i] = weightR[i];
    }
}
```

But with single-element numeric vectors, I can take advantage of Rcpp's beautiful `as` casting functionality:

```
int cluster_num = Rcpp::as<int>(cluster_num_k);
```

Trying something similar for length > 1 numeric vectors, however, leads to a crash or an error, depending on the exact variant of the syntax:

```
double weight[point_num] = Rcpp::as<double>(weightvec);
```

I don't necessarily mind the loop, but I'm a total neophyte and suspect there's a better way.  I've read through Rcpp-introduction, hadley's wiki tutorial, and RcppExamples and not yet found anything that addresses this question, but that doesn't mean I didn't just miss it.  My read of the Doxygen Rcpp docs is that `as` can cast to a STL vector but not an array (but I have a very hard time reading those docs, so I suspect I'm wrong there).  If so, I guess I could cast to a vector and thence to an array....

So my question: is there a better (fewer lines of code, more expressive code, and perhaps even able-to-avoid-a-memory-allocation) way to convert a `NumericVector` to a `double[]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ari, in the previous answer, John makes a good point.  To extend a little, there are a few issues here

- you are dealing with a library with antiquated coding standard which wants a `double[]` or `*double`
- you want to use better coding standards and take advantage of [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html).

Well, fear not, we have a simple solution. Instantantiate the `Rcpp::NumericVector X(weightvec);` as usual, and then pass it to your function `foo()` (or whatever) as

```
foo(X.begin())
```

which gives you the required `double*`, and if needed `X.size()` provides the length.  Because you come from R, you do not need to worry about scope and lifetime as you return to R afterwards.

In case you need to be more explicit, I have also used the uglier `&(X[0])`.

Also, the `Rcpp::as<>()` caster also works on `std::vector<double>`, so you can do

```
std::vector<double> x = Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> >(weightvec);
```

but apart from converting to C++ types it gains nothing here.

Finally, in case Josh or other C diehards are nearby, all this uses the fact that the `SEXP` you from R is guaranteed to have the contiguous C pointer, so you could also go via the very old school `REAL(weightvec)`.

Comment: I went with `weightR.begin()` and it works beautifully.  Thanks Dirk.

Answer (score 4):

Writing a C++ program that does not use the Standard Library (what you are referring to as the "STL") is not what I would consider to be "conventional C++."  The Standard Library is *part of* the language as defined by the Standard.  As such, using the facilities defined in the Standard is not unconventional C++.  Quite the opposite, I'd suggest that deliberately ignoring those facilities is itself unconconventional.  It's using C++ as a "better C", or a "C with classes." and that's missing the point.

Bearing this in mind, when looking at what your loop intends to accomplish my first inclination is to use `transform` to copy the source to the destination, and a `vector` as the destination.

You also have an intermediary at work here -- you first (appear to) copy `weightVec` to a newly-constructed `NumericVector`, and then copy the elements out of that -- but the `NumericVector` gets thrown away.  This seems wasteful to me.

Here is the basic pattern that I would have in mind when writing this code:

```
vector<double> weight;
transform( weightVec.begin(), weightVec.end(), back_inserter(weight), converter() );
return weight;
```

There are some syntactic bits missing here, which I can't fill in without knowing more about the compnents at play.  But given what you're doing, the philosophy seems sound.

For example, the `SEXP` object might not have `begin()` or `end()` methods.  However you are already constructing a `NumericVector` from the `SEXP` object directly, so the `SEXP` probably has analog facilities for `begin()` and `end()` that you can adopt or possibly even use directly.

The `converter()` construct I use above is a placeholder for a function, functor or lambda (in C++11) which converts a single `SEXP` element in to a `double`.  Again I don't know the details I need in order to implement this, but it must be possible since you're already doing this in another way.

Comment: "Conventional C++" criticism noted and changed.  I also linked to the code I'm wrapping.  I agree as well with the intermediary problem, but encountered problems when not doing it in two steps (e.g. putting NumericVector weightR in the function def).  I'm not super-concerned about wrapping efficiency in this particular problem (the arrays involved are fairly small, so keeping a few extra copies around is no big deal as long as it only happens once rather than inside the actual algorithm), but I'd like to learn how to do it right in the future....

Comment: John, that is all good and true "in general" yet completely ignores the Rcpp specifics which Ari clearly asked about.  There are twice as many R-related tags to his question than C++ tags :)   See my answer for a bit more Rcpp context.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to COPY data from `Rcpp::NumericVector` to C++ array, `transform()` is a good answer. But if you want to get the inner array from `Rcpp::NumericVector`, which does not include any copying, you can do exactly the same as the extracting array from `std::vector`:

```
double* arr = &vec[0];
```

where vec is a `Rcpp::NumericVector`.